# Newbie struggles with std::cin

Tags: c++, cin

I'm having an issue where a simple function appears to terminate when it reaches an std::cin request.  The compiler throws no warnings or errors and no run-time errors occur, the program simply falls back to main menu.

Snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void circle()
{
    float radius = 0.0f, diameter = 0.0f, circumference = 0.0f, area = 0.0f;
    const float pi = 3.14f;

    cout << "Enter radius." << endl;
    cin >> radius;
    cout << "Radius: " << radius << endl;
    cout << "Diameter: " << 2*radius << endl;
    cout << "Cirumference: " << 2*pi*radius << endl;
    cout << "Area: " << pi * pow(radius, 2) << endl;
}
```

The function is called from main() and is successfully called as "Enter radius" appears on the screen, but no input is requested and the last 4 statements are skipped.  The program then simply returns to main().

cin is also error free (and continues to work while playing in the main() function) so I don't think it's simply reading a bad character in the stream.

I just can't figure out why circle() quits unexpectedly.

Comment: Good request.  I never added it because I didn't think it relevant at the time.  I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it works fine on my computer. Did you debug it and does it really skips those lines? Add

```
cout << flush;
```

an the end to flush the buffer and see the results on the screen.

Remember to also clean the cin buffer before reading from it if you want it to block the executing program and wait for input from a user.

Comment: That was my problem!  I never cleaned by `cin` buffer.  `main()` had another `cin`.  It didn't occur to me that was the issue, hence why I never included the contents of `main()`.

Derp.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

It does the same on my machine when I try and run your code using `Visual Studio 2010` on `Windows XP`.

I managed to fix it by putting `getchar();` after the call to `circle()` in `main`.

Not sure why this is happening, hopefully someone can shed some more light on it.

**EDIT:

Of course it'll quit, it's because it'll run to the end of `main` which quits the app.

Answer (score 1):

`cin` doesn't request input, but just reads from stdin. So you program will print out

```
Enter radius.
```

followed by a new line. Then you can just type the radius and hit return. Did you try that?